# liquibase-maven-plugin generate changelog ERROR

Tags: liquibase

cannot generate changelog from an exist db,errors return like below:
**Invalid string encoding on createTable.remarks. To resolve, remove the invalid character on the database and try again in changeSet**
use `show variables like 'char%';`
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuIZp.png)

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after add table one by one,I find that if you add space in comment of column or table,and other special symbol,the ERROR arise.to be frankly,the ERROR message is unclear